# WeakReference vs. List<JSON> objects

Tags: c#, json, performance, garbage-collection, weak-references

I have a question.

I have json file with almost 6000 complex objects.
Each object has a few of different arrays.
I need serialize to object only for insert each object to database as simple structure.
After this I don't need it anymore.
What is more efficiency?

Using WeakReference, import and GC.Collect?
Or List, import and that's all.
Or should I implement IDisposable for second case?

Greets, Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do anything special in this case, just consume your objects GC should take care of naturally.

A WeakReference is used to reference an object but to not prevent the referenced object from being GC, I don't see any need for a WeakReference here.

Comment: And certainly no need for IDisposable.